# Attribute "tint" already defined with incompatible format

Tags: android, module, dependencies, build.gradle

While build project it shows an error

```
Error:(676) Attribute "tint" already defined with incompatible format.
Error:(329) Original attribute defined here.
refering to values.xml file
" declare-styleable name="TintableImageView">attr format="reference|color" name="tint"/>/declare-styleable>" in  "..\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml" location
```

also in build.gradle showing 
All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification. Found `version 27.0.2, 25.3.1`. Examples include `com.android.support:animated-vector-deawable:27.0.2` and `com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1`

I am including 5 modules in my app as

```
compile project(path: ':RippleEffectlibrary')
compile project(path: ':crop_lib')
compile project(path: ':rangeseekbar')
compile project(path: ':simple-crop-image-lib')
compile project(path: ':infiniteviewpager')
```

Comment: go to build>clean after that build>rebuild

Comment: clean rebuilt didnt worked.. also tried "invalidate cache and restart" but didnt solved..

Comment: why not your are using dependencies of those 5 libraries.. add this to you gradle `implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-deawable:27.0.2'` and `implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1'`

Comment: currently I'm using AS 2.3.3. first i created that project in 2.3.3 then updated AS to 3.0.1 then again i changed to 2.3.3 since i changed AS to 3.0.1 its giving such errors